# Excel - Linear Programming Model Formulas

Tags: excel, linear-programming

I'm studying for an exam and i'm having trouble with a question on the sample exam but no answers were given. Could someone help me out please? It's not strictly speaking a programming question but I was sure that I can find help on stack. :)

This is the question:

The GamesShop in the Melbourne Central complex sells two of the latest computer games, French Flop and Argentine Agony. Customer purchase patterns require that at least 20 copies of French Flop and at least 25 copies of Argentine Agony must be held in stock. Display constraints require that a total of at least 50 games and no more than 60 games be stocked. Costs average $130 for a French Flop game and $110 for an Argentine Agony game. How many of each type of game should be stocked in order to minimise costs?

I need to set up linear functions and then graph it out but I'm stuck on creating the linear formulas.
I usually set it out in a table first but i'm confused with the constraints of 50-60 games part.

I am not looking for a direct answer. I just want some guidance on how to set up the formulas functions. To me, it seems like it's lacking data although i'm not that experienced with it.

All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by letting A be the number of Argentine Agony and F that of French Flop.

*Customer purchase patterns require that at least 20 copies of French Flop and at least 25 copies of Argentine Agony must be held in stock*:

20 <= F

25 <= A

*Display constraints require that a total of at least 50 games and no more than 60 games be stocked*:

50 <= A + F <= 60.

*Costs average $130 for a French Flop game and $110 for an Argentine Agony game.*

C = 130*F + 110*A

Copy-pasting these constraints to WolframAlpha gives this graph:

[image: Feasible region plot for inequalities]

Comment: Hi @chthonicdaemon, thanks for the reply. Honestly, I got to this point. But it's here that I get stuck. See when I go to solve the cost equation substituting both A and F for 0 to get the intercepting points and what not, I don't get any answers as I have C instead of a number. In the previous examples that i've done, it was always a number and I was able to solve for A and F, the intersecting points and the corner points to find the solution area.

Comment: Try drawing these constraints on a graph. You will see the intercepts clearly. The solution will lie at one of them.

Comment: @YaserSleiman I've added the graph - you can use WolframAlpha to draw these quite quickly. You can see the vertices clearly now, and you can just plug the values into the cost function to get the lowest one, or reason that the cost goes down to the bottom left, so it must be either (30, 20) or (25, 25).

Comment: I didn't have a chance to reply earlier. But I did as you said in your second comment and was surprised to see that it actually drew the shape. It was 50 <= A + F <= 60 that was confusing me. Thank you very much. Oh and thanks for the discovery of WolframAlpha! :)